# Hadoop cluster capacity planning for monthly 100 TB data ingestion

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I need to perform the capacity planning of a Yarn based Hadoop2 cluster .

Following are the cluster related inputs I have received so far .

1. Data needs to be ingested per month around **100 TB**
2. This data volume would gradually increase approximately around around **5-10% per month**.
3. The retention period ,after processing the ingested data would be around 10 days.
4. **Hadoop 2.x** is going to be used.
5. Client is not willing to move to cloud based environment like AWS/Azure etc.

I am trying to perform the capacity planning by focusing on the following points:

- Total number of data nodes needed
- Capacity of NameNode, on the CPU
  side and on the memory side.
- Capacity of each DataNode needed, on the
  CPU side and on the memory side.
- Capacity of the EdgeNode needed, on
  the CPU side and on the memory side(considering the fact it would be
  gateway to the entire cluster for data ingestion.
- Correct replication factor for the cluster (3 or less ? any guidelines ?)
- Implementation of retention period a cluster level

If somebody has any experience on any sort of Hadoop cluster capacity planning ,please share your experience/idea on this .
In case you need any further input, please let me know .

Comment: Any input from anybody ?